# Why are some options unavailable when recording a macro in Word 2007?

Tags: images, microsoft-word-2007, macros, recording

I am trying to create a macro that works with images in Word 2007. The problem is that when I start recording my macro I can't select some options, such as the one surrounded by a red border in the image below:

[image]

Why is this happening, and what can I do to use these image options when recording a macro?